# Binding on UserControl in one UserControl instance syncing with another instance

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls

I have a really weird issue that I'm almost convinced is a bug.

I have three UserControls, FolderView, LocalFolderView, RemoteFolderView. LocalFolderView and RemoteFolderView both inherit FolderView and are used in two other controls, LocalExplorer and RemoteExplorer, respectively.

LocalExplorer/RemoteExplorer have a list of strings, which I bind to the FolderView.

The problem is whenever I have more than 1 instance of LocalExplorer/RemoteExplorer, the ListBox in the FolderView for both Explorers show the same items, yet the dependency properties for the controls are seemingly different.

The code is really long so I'll try to condense as much as I can. Currently, I believe the issue is with the way I'm binding things.

Here's the control I have more than one instance of that exhibits the bug:

LocalExplorer.xaml (RemoteExplorer.xaml follows identical pattern):

```
<UserControl x:Class="LocalExplorer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Width="Auto"
             Height="Auto" 
             ClipToBounds="True"
             x:Name="explorer">
    <local:ExplorerBase Path="{Binding ElementName=explorer, Path=Path}" Orientation="{Binding ElementName=explorer, Path=Orientation}">
        <local:ExplorerBase.FolderView>
            <local:LocalFolderView x:Name="FolderView" Path="{Binding Path, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:LocalExplorer}}}"/>
        </local:ExplorerBase.FolderView>
    </local:ExplorerBase>
</UserControl>
```

LocalExplorer.xaml.cs (RemoteExplorer.xaml.cs follows identical pattern):

```
public partial class Explorer : UserControl
{
    #region Explorer

    public Explorer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Dependency Properties

    public static DependencyProperty PathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Path", typeof(string), typeof(Explorer), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(PathProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PathProperty, value);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Next is ExplorerBase, which houses UI logic specific to all Explorers:

ExplorerBase.cs:

```
public partial class ExplorerBase : Control
{
    public ExplorerBase()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ExplorerBase);
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.ApplyTemplate();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FolderViewProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FolderView", typeof(object), typeof(ExplorerBase), null);
    public object FolderView
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(FolderViewProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(FolderViewProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty PathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Path", typeof(string), typeof(ExplorerBase), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(PathProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PathProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I template it using Themes/Generic.xaml approach:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Imagin.Controls:ExplorerBase}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Imagin.Controls:ExplorerBase">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding FolderView}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And lastly, the FolderView, which I believe is what has the bug. The FolderView is a base for the actual controls used, LocalFolderView and RemoteFolderView. Note, the bug occurs regardless of whether or not I use both LocalExplorer and RemoteExplorer, or 1 of both. I have only tested a total of two instances at once.

FolderView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FolderView"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Height="Auto" 
            Width="Auto"
            x:Name="folderView">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
        <Imagin.Data:InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InverseBoolToVisibility" />
        <Grid>
            <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" AllowDrop="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:FolderView}}}" SelectionMode="Extended" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BindableFile}">
                        <local:Thumbnail FilePath="{Binding Path}" IsCheckBoxEnabled="False" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}" Title="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BindableFolder}">
                        <local:Thumbnail FilePath="{Binding Path}" IsCheckBoxEnabled="False" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}" Title="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.Resources>
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
            <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:FolderView}}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderThickness="0" AlternationCount="2" GridLinesVisibility="None" HeadersVisibility="Column" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AllowDrop="True">
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

FolderView.xaml.cs:

```
public abstract partial class FolderView : UserControl
{
    #region DependencyProperties

    public static DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<BindablePath>), typeof(FolderView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<BindablePath>(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    public ObservableCollection<BindablePath> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<BindablePath>)GetValue(ItemsProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty PathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Path", typeof(string), typeof(FolderView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnPathChanged));
    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(PathProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PathProperty, value);
        }
    }
    private static void OnPathChanged(DependencyObject Object, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderView FolderView = (FolderView)Object;
        FolderView.Refresh();
        FolderView.SearchTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public virtual void GetItems(string Path, out List<string> Folders, out List<string> Files)
    {
        Folders = default(List<string>);
        Files = default(List<string>);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Refreshes current path with contents.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void Refresh()
    {
        //Used to debug property values at runtime. So far the values for each object instance are unique.
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this))
        {
            string name = descriptor.Name;
            object value = descriptor.GetValue(this);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", name, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates controls with actual items via binding. We must do this on UI thread. This occurs immediately after <Refresh()>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Folders"></param>
    /// <param name="Files"></param>
    public virtual void Populate(List<FtpListItem> Folders, List<FtpListItem> Files)
    {
    }

    public virtual void Populate(List<string> Folders, List<string> Files)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region FolderView

    public FolderView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

LocalFolderView.cs (RemoteFolderView.cs follows identical pattern):

```
public sealed class LocalFolderView : FolderView
{
    public override void GetItems(string Path, out List<string> Folders, out List<string> Files)
    {
        //These are my own functions
        Folders = Directory.GetDirectories(Path);
        Files = Directory.GetFiles(Path, null);
    }

    public override void Populate(List<string> Folders, List<string> Files)
    {
        int NumFolders = Folders.Count, NumFiles = Files.Count;
        this.IsEmpty = NumFolders == 0 && NumFiles == 0 ? true : false;
        if (Folders == null || Files == null || (NumFolders == 0 && NumFiles == 0)) return;
        for (int j = 0, Count = NumFolders; j < Count; j++)
        {
            this.Items.Add(new BindableFolder(Folders[j]));
        }
        for (int j = 0, Count = NumFiles; j < Count; j++)
        {
            this.Items.Add(new BindableFile(Files[j]));
        }
    }

    public override void Refresh()
    {
        base.Refresh();
        this.Items.Clear();
        //If directory doesn't exist, we don't want to enter it.
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(this.Path)) return;
        List<string> Folders = null;
        List<string> Files = null;
        string CurrentPath = this.Path;

        BackgroundWorker Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        Worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.GetItems(CurrentPath, out Folders, out Files);
        };
        Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            //Start populating items
            var DispatcherOperation = Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.Populate(Folders, Files)));
        };
        Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Things to note:

1. The DataGrids in the FolderViews in both instances also populate with identical items.
2. The path property for each FolderView instance is different.
3. This only occurs after populating the second instance with items, then attempting to populate the first. If I populate the first instance first, nothing happens to the second at all.
4. When I say both instances populate with identical items, I mean that if I populate the first, the first's items appear in the second. And if I populate the second, the second's items appear in the first.
5. And also, when I say "populate", I just mean I'm setting the `Path` property to the FolderView.

Things I've tried:

1. Changing the way I bind. For instance, instead of binding like `Binding ElementName=explorer, Path=Property`, I would change it to `Binding Property, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControlType}}`.
2. Removing `x:Name` properties from various elements.
3. Dumping FolderView's properties/values. An example of that in source above.

Honestly, I don't know how else to debug. IS this a bug or is my binding logic not so logical?

**Edit**

Here's how I display two Explorer instances:

```
<local:LocalExplorer />
<local:RemoteExplorer/>
```

Given they are both their own instances, I do not see how either could mistakenly bind to another, especially considering how deeply nested the ListBoxes are in the visual tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the dependency property registration of Items property.

```
public static DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items",
typeof(ObservableCollection<BindablePath>), typeof(FolderView),
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<BindablePath>(), 
                     FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

As you can see **registration is static and will be registered on Type and not on instance**. Since default value provided is `new ObservableCollection<BindablePath>()`, same instance will be shared across all instances of FolderView. That's why, whenever any new item is added, it is shown in all the instances because in a nutshell, Items property is referring to same instance.

> As a thumb rule, you should always avoid providing new instance for
>   any reference types during dependency property registration.

---

**Solution**:

Make default value as null and instead initialize it to new instance from constructor of FolderView (per instance).

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```